# Using a complex "type" field with Jackson's polymorphism

Tags: java, jackson

Lets say we have the following class hierarchy:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "Dog"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat") }
)
public abstract class Animal {
}

class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
```

Serializing a `Dog` instance would add a `type: "Dog"` property, and that same property will be used to construct the correct instance during deserialization. My question is can I change the type of the `type` field, to not be a simple string field but lets say a complex `{ key: "", value: ""}` object (`class AnimalKey { String key; String value; }`). I've looked at the `JsonTypeIdResolver` annotation, but it seems it uses a string for the type. Could this be achieved, perhaps by some custom converters or (de)serializers?